# When touching 'Back' button in UINavigationBar, bar changes, but screen doesn't

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

When testing my iOS 7 app on iOS 8, I noticed that sometimes when I touch the 'back' button on a UINavigationBar, the bar itself updates -- i.e., displays what it should display for the previous screen -- but the screen itself does not update.

When this happens, I can hit the back button again and again until I'm at the root view controller. The Navigation Bar updates, but the main screen never changes.

I've never seen this behavior on iOS 7, so I assume something is different about iOS 8. It doesn't happen all the time, but it's easy enough to make happen. Just need to go up and down the stack a few times.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some code that shows how you're setting up your navigation controller as well as how you're pushing view controllers onto it?

Comment: This was a known bug in one of the early betas. Are you using the final release of Xcode 6 and the iOS 8 SDK?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm using Xcode 6.0.1, with a deployment target of 7.1. Now that you ask me, I'm not sure how to find out what version of SDK I'm using. I've been working on this project for about 6 months and it has been awhile since I've updated. I will do that right now.

Comment: Oh, duh. I have Xcode set to auto update, so I'm running the latest stable version of the sdk

Comment: I think I've narrowed the problem down to a single controller, so will try to post some code in a bit.